# Skyrim updated to 1.5 but no 'cinematic killcam'

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

One thing I loved about Fallout 3 was the slow motion cinematic killcams.  So when I heard they were coming to Skyrim I was made up.

Yesterday my copy of Skyrim (PC) updated itself in Steam.  I loaded it.  I see that the version is 1.5 (1.5 and then some more numbers).  No killcams whatsoever.  I've killed about 10 enemies without getting a killcam.  Is it something you have to turn on?  I couldn't see a setting anywhere.   It is supposed to work for projectile weapons and magic.  I'm using a bow and arrow which in my book is a projectile weapon!

Edit (14/04/2012):  To update this,  I have had a few killcams happen now.  They're pretty neat.  Worth the wait :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in there, the new ones have made me laugh (especially the two-hander head banging)... But they are random. Getting them to show up is not a guaranteed thing. All I can suggest is keep playing.. I often work my combats to be 1 on 1 or 1 on 2 and such and I get the kill cam slo-mo quite often.

Comment: Thanks.   I guess I thought they'd be every kill. I seem to remember seeing them almost every time in FO3 but then again I did use VATS most of the time.

Comment: Yeah, VATS was a kill cam shot almost every time, especially with the plasma rifles. Skyrim is a bit more tricky in that regard.

Comment: What's your source on them being random? I'm pretty sure they're purely random.

Comment: Many Many hours of game play for the most part.

Comment: I've never had a Magic killcam on a target that had 100% HP.