# When determines when one gets a magic or bow killcam?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What determines when you do a finishing move?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35077/what-determines-when-you-do-a-finishing-move)
>   [Skyrim updated to 1.5 but no 'cinematic killcam'](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60149/skyrim-updated-to-1-5-but-no-cinematic-killcam)

In the latest Skyrim update, killcams for bow/arrows and magic was added.

But it does not happen with every kill.

What determines when the killcam happens? It does not seem to be random and I have heard things like it being the last enemy in the area.

Comment: Mark: A finishing move is difference from a killcam.

Comment: They may not be the same per se, but they always trigger together, so there really is no use distinguishing between them.

Comment: Are there finishing moves for arrows/magic now?

Comment: @Zeno Yep, it was added in the 1.5 update.

Comment: i had a significant increase when i got my one-handed skill higher, dont know if it is a coincidence

Answer (score 0):

My only possible theory is that first off, the enemy must be below 75% health. This increases the chance of the killcam although if you are a one hit killer this is pretty much useless. Second off, from what I know, to ensure the highest chance of a killcam, make it a sneak kill. This is all I know so far but I'm testing a lot of different theories.