# How do I trigger cinematics for projectile kills in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

I'm running Skyrim on a PS3, fully updated (2.5).  However, I can't seem to trigger the new kill cinematics I've heard of.  My character level is 78, and archery skill is 100, but I still haven't seen any of the new animations.

Is there something particular I need to do to trigger them?  What might prevent the animations from being triggered?

Comment: I'm slightly confused.  What exactly are we meaning by "execution"?  I don't recall having much trouble pulling off one-shot kills in Skyrim, last I played.  Are there supposed to be new, special animations for ranged kills - like there are for some melee kills?

Comment: Got some clarification from UESP.  Edited the question for clarity.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Oh Just I havent played in a while so im just getting the slo-mo kills now basicly getting to grips with it now, this is what I want to pull off http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ZHSw4uWiZY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skyrim updated to 1.5 but no 'cinematic killcam'](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/60149/skyrim-updated-to-1-5-but-no-cinematic-killcam) and [What determines when you do a finishing move](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35077/what-determines-when-you-do-a-finishing-move)

Answer (score 2):

> For the PS3. Performing a finishing move can happen randomly in a fight but can be
>   done on command by tapping R1 and flicking the left analog stick
>   forward. A finisher factors in how strong the player is against its
>   enemy and how the player's character is positioned.

Also, after doing a bit of testing, to perform Magic/Archery finishing moves(besides the randomly occurring ones), you need to have the target moving, having less than 5% of their health, or be unaware of your presence, and your attack be strong enough to kill them.

and I think your problem is:

> Since Magic/Archery finishing moves were added in patch 1.5, you will
>   need an Internet connection to your PS3 to install/update to the
>   current patch.

If you want to learn more:
http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Finishing_Moves

Comment: just to clarify, any one of those conditions will meet the requirement to potentially trigger the cinematics, doesn't have to be all of them.